# AngularJS - Click event (in directive) triggers when anywhere in the parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm going to do my best to explain my issue - bear with me.

This whole thing is a directive for file selection:

[image]

The directive has an ng-transclude component that contains a few directives, contained in their own divs.

Parent directive:

```
<div class="extra-cells">
    <div ng-transclude class="extra-cells-row"></div>
</div>
```

ng-transclude content:

```
<div file-upload-directive>
     <div bo-if="config.drive">
         <div google-picker>
             <div>Google Drive</div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div bo-if="config.dropbox">
         <div dropbox-chooser>
             <div>Dropbox</div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div bo-if="config.link">
         <div ng-click="selectLink()">
             <div>Paste a link</div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

ng-transclude content(visual):

[image]

The click event in the offending (dropbox) directive fires when I click anywhere in the highlighted section.

```js
dropboxChooserModule.directive('dropboxChooser', function(dropboxChooserService) {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      widget: '=',
      options: '=',
      extensions: '=',
    },
    template: '<div class="">' +
      '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
      '<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file"/></div>',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("click", function(event) {
        dropboxChooserService.choose({
          success: function(files) {},
          cancel: function() {}
        })
      });
    },
    replace: true
  };
});
```

[image]

The question is, naturally, what is causing it to trigger and how do I make it stop. It should trigger only when the element with the dropbox directive is clicked.

Comment: What should be the case according to your needs?

Comment: I should have asked a question in my question, huh. It should trigger only when the element which has the directive is clicked.

Comment: Try removing the `replace` property on the dropbox directive

Comment: @CorySilva I hoped you were right, but nope.

Comment: I could help you if it is possible to have the running code, either on plunkr.co or your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the input element inside the directive seems to have "fixed" the problem.